# this is my manifest version 2 but javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I want to make Google Chrome Extension for a Scheduler Project. I have made the manifest but it reads only the HTML but does not read the JavaScript.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "FCIS-ASU Scheduler",
  "description": "chrome extension that you can schedule your events, meetings,and tasks.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",`enter code here`
    "default_title": "FCIS-ASU Scheduler",
    "default_popup": "HtmlPage1.html"

  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is because you haven't told extension about any js file. You need to specify `background` or `content_scripts` field value based on your need.
You should go through this http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html once again and read other documenntation.

Comment: "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.mywebsite.com/*"],
        "js":["scheduling.js"],
  "run_at":     "document_idle",
        "all_frames": false
        
    }
 ],